# Stealin' Bill - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

[image: Stealin' Bill]

Clues: [contextual images] W

Instructions: Name That Actor

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ a _ _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden actor is:

> [**ROBIN WILLI[A]MS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Williams)

Because the rebus is a clue for...

> MISTER (the spray bottle) + W + ANCHOR, which altogether makes the name '**Mr. W*nker**'. Note that this is *not* an obscene nickname intended to be applied to the late actor in question (by no means), but actually the name of a character in Robin Williams' *Happy Days* spin-off *[Mork & Mindy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy)* (as per the Wikipedia description, "the landlord of Fred and Cora's music store in Season 1").
>
>  The joke is that Williams [apparently](https://metro.co.uk/2014/08/12/8-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-robin-williams-4829324/) made sure this character name appeared in an episode of the TV show as a prank, knowing full well that while the word was not widely known (and fairly meaningless) in the US at the time, in the UK it was (and still is) actually considered an obscenity, meaning that the episode would have to be heavily censored when broadcast there!

Note the title also...

> *Stealin'* is a synonym of *Robbin'*, leading us to **Robin**, and *Bill* is a shortening of the name *William*, leading us to **Williams**.